# How can I manually update my project's Android Gradle Plugin?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When I start Android Studio, it tells me

> Android Gradle plugin 7.4.2 has an upgrade available.  Start the AGP Upgrade Assistant to update this project's AGP version

If I click 'Start AGP Upgrade Assistant', the view comes up but is perpetually loading.  I also find this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.android.ide.common.repository.AgpVersion$Companion.tryParse, parameter value
> at com.android.ide.common.repository.AgpVersion$Companion.tryParse(AgpVersion.kt)
> at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.upgrade.AgpUpgradeRefactoringProcessorKt.isUpdatablePluginDependency(AgpUpgradeRefactoringProcessor.kt:1101)
> at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.upgrade.AgpVersionRefactoringProcessor.findComponentUsages(AgpVersionRefactoringProcessor.kt:160)
> at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.upgrade.AgpUpgradeComponentRefactoringProcessor.computeIsAlwaysNoOpForProject(AgpUpgradeRefactoringProcessor.kt:904)
> at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.upgrade.AgpUpgradeComponentRefactoringProcessor$isAlwaysNoOpForProject$1.run(AgpUpgradeRefactoringProcessor.kt:795)
> at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService.runReadActionInSmartMode(DumbService.java:143)
> at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.upgrade.AgpUpgradeComponentRefactoringProcessor.isAlwaysNoOpForProject(AgpUpgradeRefactoringProcessor.kt:795)
> at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.upgrade.ui.UpgradeAssistantWindowModelKt.activeComponentsForNecessity(UpgradeAssistantWindowModel.kt:731)
> at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.upgrade.ui.UpgradeAssistantWindowModelKt.access$activeComponentsForNecessity(UpgradeAssistantWindowModel.kt:1)
> at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.upgrade.ui.UpgradeAssistantWindowModel.refreshTree$populateNecessity(UpgradeAssistantWindowModel.kt:492)
> at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.upgrade.ui.UpgradeAssistantWindowModel.refreshTree(UpgradeAssistantWindowModel.kt:497)
> at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.upgrade.ui.UpgradeAssistantWindowModel.setEnabled(UpgradeAssistantWindowModel.kt:456)
> at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.upgrade.ui.UpgradeAssistantWindowModel.access$setEnabled(UpgradeAssistantWindowModel.kt:86)
> at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.upgrade.ui.UpgradeAssistantWindowModel$parseAndSetEnabled$1.run(UpgradeAssistantWindowModel.kt:450)
> at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.lambda$smartInvokeLater$9(DumbServiceImpl.java:528)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:209)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$100(TransactionGuardImpl.java:21)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$1.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:191)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:838)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$3.run(ApplicationImpl.java:454)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:74)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:114)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:36)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:909)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:756)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$5(IdeEventQueue.java:437)
> at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:787)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:436)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:105)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.java:615)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:434)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:838)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:480)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Manually invoking the AGP Upgrade Assistant does no better.
The project is a React Native project.

> Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 4
> Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.11090377, built on November 13, 2023
> Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231 aarch64
> VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
> macOS 14.1.1
> GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
> Memory: 2048M
> Cores: 10
> Metal Rendering is ON
> Registry:
> external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
> ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false

Answer (score 0):

Tools > AGP Upgrade assistant... > choose the version and run selected steps

I appologise! Did not see last statement.

in gradle.properties file paste these at the end:

```
android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true
android.nonTransitiveRClass=false
android.nonFinalResIds=false
```

and in gradle-wrapper.properties modify this line:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-bin.zip
```

Comment: Are these changes likely required indefinitely?  Or just long enough to get to 8.2 after which they can be removed?

Comment: Can you confirm you meant for this first block to pasted in to gradle.properties, not gradle.build?  Putting it in the build file did not fair well.

With those 2 changes made to their respective properties file, Launching the AGP Upgrade Assistant no long crashes, but just continues to spin "Loading".  Over 5 minutes so far, but I'll leave it going for a while.

Comment: these are the changes required to update from gradle plug in version 7 to the most recent version which of this time is 8.2. I did get the name of one of the files wrong. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I appear to be on 8.1.1 currently.  Is a upgrade done in multiple steps?  Perhaps it part way there one time and I did not notice.  Either way the upgrade assistant never finishes "Loading"